# How do I find the decimal value of a trig function?

Tags: trigonometry

Let's say I need the decimal value of $\sin/\cos/\tan$ of $33°6'13''$, or just any non-standard value. How do I do that without using a calculator?

Comment: In general, without a calculator, you don't. The usual approach is to approximate via a series expansion. This is btw what a calculator does

Comment: Back in the day, you went and bought a [book with tables of values](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Bernegger_Manuale_137.jpg), precisely because it was a hassle to compute by hand.

Comment: @G.Chiusole This is really strange. I'm looking at a question right now that requires me to do an arcsine (64/91) but on the exam I had it on I was asked to use a 4-function calculator only. What am I missing?

Comment: @Ivan my guess is that you were supposed to use addition theorems and the like to bring it to a known form

Comment: @G.Chiusole Do you know what those formulas are?

Comment: @Ivan Short answer: one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). On another note, the value of $\text{arcsine}(64/91)$ is about $0.24828945029 \pi$. So I'm not sure how the problem was supposed to be solved.

Comment: The way to find out about your previous exams: ask the instructor.  We do not know what else was in that course.